# check if div w/ class x exists on page w/ Jekyll Liquid

Tags: html, github, jekyll, liquid

How can I check if a div with certain class `x` exists on page?

```
{% if page.div.class == x %}
  <script></script>
{% endif %}
```

Would this work?

Comment: Can't you use javascript for this?

Comment: I'm not too handy w/ js yet, jekyll uses liquid, so I got a basic understanding of that.

Comment: Okay, with JS it is very simple, I can post JS answer if you want, but I don't know about jekll.

Comment: sure, go right ahead, not going to mark it solved tho fyi.

Answer (score 1):

With JavaScript and `document.querySelector()`, you can select the first element within the document that matches your specified selector.
For example:

```
const targetElement = document.querySelector('.x') // .x is class you are looking for

if (targetElement) console.log('element with class of x exists')
```

If an element exists on your page it will return that element, otherwise `null` is being returned.

Checkout [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)